# How to run a beam pipeline written in python on apache flink

Tags: python, apache-flink, apache-beam

I have used python sdk to write my beam pipelines. I am using celery as a wrapper over direct runner.
I want to use flink runner to parallelise my load.

As per the documentation, you need to give your job as a jar file for flink runner.

Can you point me to any resources where I can use both apache beam python sdk and apache flink?
Any samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now (`Apache Beam 2.2.0`) there is no support for Apache Flink Runner for Apache Beam Python SDK. When you try to use `FlinkRunner` in your Python pipeline you will get `ValueError`:

> ValueError: Unexpected pipeline runner: FlinkRunner. Valid values are
>   DirectRunner, EagerRunner, DataflowRunner, TestDataflowRunner or the
>   fully qualified name of a PipelineRunner subclass.

You can see this in source code, here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/d11b9e9560131f55b418a13a7d10401c2135fb33/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/runner.py#L62